# Python- list with arrays shape issues

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, dimensions

I'm creating a code to run a perceptron algorithm and I can't create a random matrix the way I need it:

```
from random import choice
from numpy import array, dot, random
unit_step = lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else 1
import numpy as np
m=3 #this will be the number of rows
allys=[]
for j in range(m):
    aa=np.random.rand(1,3)
    tt=np.random.rand(3)
    yy=dot(aa,tt)
    ally = [aa, yy]
    allys.append(ally)
print  "allys", allys

w = random.rand(3)
errors = []
eta = 0.2
n = 10
x=[1,3]

for i in xrange(n):
    print i 
    x, expected = choice(allys)
    print "x", x
```

And I get the problem here:

```
    result = dot(x,w)    
    error = expected - unit_step(result) 
    errors.append(error) 
    w += eta * error * x 
    print x, expected, w, error, result, errors
```

The log says

> w += eta * error * x 
>   ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,) doesn't
>   match the broadcast shape (1,3)

The idea is to get result looping randomly over the "table" allys.

How can I solve this? What is shape(3,)?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the "allys"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message actually tells you what is wrong. The result of your multiplication is a (1,3) array (2D array, one row, three columns), whereas you try to add it into a 3-element vector.

Both arrays have three elements in a row, so if you do this:

```
w = w + eta * error * x
```

there will be no error on that line, but the resulting vector will actually be a (1,3) array. That is unwanted, because then your `dot` does not work.

There are several ways to fix the problem, but possibly the easiest to read is to reshape `x` for the calculation to be a 3-element vector (1D array):

```
w += eta * error * x.reshape(3,)
```

Possibly a cleaner solution would be to define `w` as a (1,3) 2D array, as well, and then transpose `w` for the `dot`. This is really a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

For numpy arrays, shape attribute returns array's dimensionality. In your case, `w.shape` is `(3,)`.  This means that `w` is a one-dimensional array with 3 elements. In turn, `x.shape` is `(1,3)`, which means that `x` is a two-dimensional array with one row and 3 columns. You are getting an error, because the interpreter is confused on how to match the shapes. I am not sure what you are trying to do, so it's hard to suggest the solution. But you might want to try reshaping one of the arrays. For example, `x = x.reshape((3,))` for adapting the shape of x to w.